# gwcode_catmenu - {cat_image} and image sizes/manipulations

Tags: categories, gwcode-categories

We've got some categories being output using gwcode catmenu (http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-catmenu/documentation) but can't seem to find a way of outputting a certain image size (based on image manipulations setup in the file upload preferences),

The code is as follows:

```
 {exp:gwcode_catmenu cat_url_title="{segment_2}" active_branch_only="yes" depth="1" style="linear"}
    <li>
      <span class="product-text"><h2>{cat_name}</h2></span> 
      <span class="product-image"><img src="{cat_image}" alt="{cat_name}" /></span>
    </li>
 {/exp:gwcode_catmenu}
```

This works, but outputs the original image size, we want to do something like:

```
 {exp:gwcode_catmenu cat_url_title="{segment_2}" active_branch_only="yes" depth="1" style="linear"}
    <li>
      <span class="product-text"><h2>{cat_name}</h2></span> 
      <span class="product-image"><img src="{cat_image:small}" alt="{cat_name}" /></span>
    </li>
 {/exp:gwcode_catmenu}
```

To output the small version of the image, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like GWcode CatMenu currently supports calling alternate versions of category images, but you could do this in a [really quick plugin](http://pkg.io) pretty easily. Your key function would look something like this:

```
function get_size()
{
    $image = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('image');
    $size = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('size');
    $pos = strrpos($image, '/');
    if($pos !== false)
    {
        $image = substr_replace($image, '/_'.$size.'/', $pos, 1);
    }
    return $image;
}
```

So your plugin in the template might look like:

```
{exp:my_plugin:get_size image="{cat_image}" size="{small}"}
```